# Ignore controller route attribute for a specific action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I've got many actions on my controller and I want to use a specific route only for one action if possible.
I'm looking for a way to override the route defined at the controller level.

```cs
[Route("api/candidate/attached-file")]
public class AttachedFileController : Controller
    {
        //overriding controller route
        [HttpPost("api/candidate/{id}/attached-file")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AttachFile(string id, [FromBody] AttachedFile file)
        {
            ...
        }

        //using controller route
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(string id) {}

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAll() {}

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

For ignoring the route method of controller use like below:

```
[Route("/api/customControllerName/getCustomMethodName")]
public ActionResult GetCustomAll() {
}
```

using [Route("/")] ignores the api route addressings.

```
[Route("api/candidate/attached-file")]
public class AttachedFileController : Controller
    {
        //overriding controller route
        [HttpPost("api/candidate/{id}/attached-file")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AttachFile(string id, [FromBody] AttachedFile file)
        {
            ...
        }

        //using controller route
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Get(string id) {}

        [Route("/api/test/value")]
        public ActionResult GetCustomAll() {
        }
    }
```

So,By calling api/test/value address GetCustomAll() method will be called.